# Frogs spinning in a pot

Tags: combinatorics

In the classic jumping frogs game, we have 15 frogs on a circular dish, each in a pot. The dish is spinning and every few seconds it stops abruptly, so the frogs jump and land again either in their original pot or in one of the two neighboring.
In how many ways can they be rearranged after they fall? All frogs are different.

> I have calculated it to be $610+(377+1)*2$ but it doesn't seem correct to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you calculate this, and why doesn't it seem right to you?

Comment: To clarify, there are 15 frogs, and each frog can be in one of three places, and you want to know how many different ways there are to place all 15 frogs in a pot?

Comment: No, each frog is in one pot, then they jump and they land in either the same pot or one of the two neigbouring.

Comment: So after they jump, we can have multiple frogs in the same pot? (potentially 3 in one pot)

Comment: If that were the case, the answer would be $3^{15}$. Since $610$ and $377$ are Fibbonacci numbers, I suspect the question wants to know how many ways are there for the frogs to land such that each pot ends up with exactly one frog, and there is some sort of recursive formula to arrive at the answer. Of course, this is all speculation.

Comment: @bonsoon: no, each frog occupies only one pot.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 correct. If the pots (and frogs!) were in a line instead of circle, the solution would be a fibbonacci numbers with $F_1=1, F_2=2$ and so on; but the circular arrangement confuses me.

Comment: @PradeepSuny can you update the question, so that the problem can be understood completely without having to read through the comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **linear case** we get Fibonacci numbers because each of the $n$ frogs they either stay put or exchange position with one of their neighbors. One can think of this as tiling some $1\times n$ space with $1\times 1$ dominos (corresponding to the frogs that stay put) and $1\times 2$ dominos (corresponding to the pair of frogs that exchange positions). Denote $g_n$ to be this number of linear arrangements for $n$ frogs. Then $g_1 = 1$ and $g_2 = 2$, and for each $n\ge 3$, we have $g_n = g_{n-1} + g_{n-2}$, because if the first frog stays put, then we have $g_{n-1}$ many ways to arrange the rest, and if the first frog exchanges with the second frog, then we have $g_{n-2}$ many ways. Hence the recurrence, which is just the Fibonacci numbers (shifted). Here we have $g_{13} = 377$, $g_{14} = 610$.

For the **circular case**, there are several interpretations of what you may want.

In the simplest situation where the pots are all fixed in place (so we will ignore circular symmetry for now), and assuming the frogs will either stay in place or exchange with one of the neighbors. Denote $a_n$ to be the number of outcomes for $n$ many frogs. Then looking at frog number 1, it can either

(1) stay in place, so the rest of the $n-1$ frogs are in a line, giving $g_{n-1}$ many ways;

(2) exchange with frog 2, giving $g_{n-2}$ many ways;

(3) exchange with frog $n$, giving $g_{n-2}$ many ways.

So this gives $a_n = g_{n-1} + 2g_{n-2}$.

Now, there is also the situation where all the frogs jump to the left, or all the frogs jump to the right. Then in this case we have $a_n = g_{n-1} + 2g_{n-2} +2 $. (However if you take rotational symmetry into consideration, these two extra configurations are just rotationally the same no frog moved.) With $n = 15$, it seems to agree with what you got.

However, as the circular dish is spinning, it seems to me that we should take rotational symmetry into consideration, then we will get $a_n = g_{n-1} + 2g_{n-2}$.

If there are any other missing ways of how the frogs can move, then we will need to account for those. Otherwise we have our result.

Comment: The pots are fixed on a rotating disk. Once it stops, the frogs jump and can land either in their original pot or in one of the two neighbourings (the left or the right). Consider that the direction of the rotation of the disk does not affect the frog's new position. They may all shift to the left or to the right or just flip positions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two special cases- if frog $1$ moves clockwise and frog $2$ moves clockwise, then they all must move clockwise. The same holds for counterclockwise. In all other cases, each frog must either stay in place, or switch places with a neighbor. First, we think of the frogs as being in a line. When a frog stays in place, we write down $1$. When two frogs switch places, we write a $2$. These numbers will add up to $15$, so we're asking how many integer compositions of $15$ there are with no part greater than $2$. This is counted by the Fibonacci numbers. The $n$-th Fibonacci number $F_n$ counts the number of integer composition of $n-1$ with no part greater than $2$. These rearrangements are counted by $F_{16}=987$.

However, there's one problem with my argument above. By treating the frogs as being in a line instead of a circle, we forget that we can also allow frog $1$ and frog $15$ to switch places. Hence, we also need to count the rearrangements where this happens. Assuming $1$ and $15$ swap positions, we can then treat frogs $2$ through $14$ as being in a line, and do the same thing above. Since there are $13$ frogs left whose positions have not been decided, we count these rearrangements using $F_{14}=377$. This time, there's no problem treating the remaining frogs as being in a line, as frogs $2$ and $14$ are not neighbors.

The total number of these rearrangements is $987+377+2$, which is the same as your answer.

In general, if there are $n$ frogs with $n\geq 3$, then this is counted by $F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}+2$